# Update my state after PATCH request - useReducer, context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-reducer

I'm successfully updating my plant object to my cluster, but it takes a page reload in order for me to get that updated data. I'm assuming that I may need a useEffect to call my fetch again but I'm unsure how I would do that after my PATCH request.
Does anyone have any suggestions to how I would fetch my updated data after I've updated.

Context

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'

export const PlantsContext = createContext()

export const plantsReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_PLANTS':
            return { 
                plants: action.payload 
            }
        case 'CREATE_PLANT':
            return {
                plants: [action.payload, ...state.plants]
            }
        case 'DELETE_PLANT':
            return {
                plants: state.plants.filter((p) => p._id !== action.payload._id)
            }
        case 'UPDATE_PLANT':
            return {
                plants: state.plants.map((p) => p._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : p)
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const PlantsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(plantsReducer, {
        plants: null
    })

    return (
        <PlantsContext.Provider value={{...state, dispatch}}>
            { children }
        </PlantsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

My 'update' function inside PlantDetails component, setting a new water date

```
const updatePlant = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    plant.nextWaterDate = newWaterDate

    const response = await fetch("api/plants/" + plant._id, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify(plant),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    const json = await response.json()

    if(response.ok) {
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_PLANT", payload: json })
    }
  }
```

My Home component where that update should render through after PATCH request

```
const Home = () => {
  const { plants, dispatch } = usePlantsContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPlants = async () => {
      console.log("called");
      // ONLY FOR DEVELOPMENT!
      const response = await fetch("/api/plants");
      const json = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({ type: "SET_PLANTS", payload: json });
      }
    };
    fetchPlants();
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="plants">
        {plants &&
          plants.map((plant) => <PlantDetails key={plant._id} plant={plant} />)}
      </div>
      <PlantForm />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

usePlantContext

```
import { PlantsContext } from "../context/PlantContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

export const usePlantsContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(PlantsContext)
    if(!context) {
        throw Error('usePlantsContext must be used inside an PlantsContext Provider')
    }
    return context
}
```

Complete PlantsDetails Component

```
import { usePlantsContext } from "../hooks/usePlantsContext";
import formatDistanceToNow from "date-fns/formatDistanceToNow";
import { useState } from "react";
import CalendarComponent from "./CalendarComponent";
const PlantDetails = ({ plant }) => {
  const [watered, setWatered] = useState(false)
  const [newWaterDate, setNewWaterDate] = useState("")
  const { dispatch } = usePlantsContext();
  const handleClick = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/plants/" + plant._id, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      dispatch({ type: "DELETE_PLANT", payload: json });
    }
  };
  const updatePlant = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    plant.nextWaterDate = newWaterDate

    const response = await fetch("api/plants/" + plant._id, {
      method: "PATCH",
      body: JSON.stringify(plant),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    const json = await response.json()

    if(response.ok) {
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_PLANT", payload: json })
    }
    // setWatered(false)
  }
  return (
    <div className="plant-details">
      <h4>{plant.plantName}</h4>
      <p>{plant.quickInfo}</p>
      <p>
        {formatDistanceToNow(new Date(plant.createdAt), { addSuffix: true })}
      </p>
      <span onClick={handleClick}>delete</span>
      <div>
        <p>next water date: {plant.nextWaterDate}</p>
        {/* <input type="checkbox" id="toWater" onChange={() => setWatered(true)}/> */}
        <label value={watered} for="toWater">watered</label>
        <CalendarComponent setNextWaterDate={setNewWaterDate}/>
      </div>
      <button onClick={updatePlant}>update</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default PlantDetails;
```

Plant Controller

```
const updatePlant = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "No plant" })
    }

    const plant = await Plant.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {
        ...req.body
    })

    if (!plant) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "No plant" })
    }
    res.status(200).json(plant)
}
```

Thank you for looking at my question, would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Is your Home component wrapped with the PlantsContextProvider? It would be helpful if you could also provide usePlantsContext implementation

Comment: I've wrapped my whole <App /> with my context provider. I think my issue may be the reducer and the 'UPDATE_PLANT' case itself

Comment: The reducer looks good. I tried to create a reproducible example with mocked requests in this [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-matan-nkg1lq?file=/src/App.js:519-530) and all seem to work fine. The updated nextWaterDate is shown properly without reloading.

Comment: It does update but its a step behind, really confused

Comment: I've added the complete plantDetails component

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by `does update but its a step behind`.
Are you sure that  the update api returns the updated plant and not the entity before the update?

Comment: Apologies, I select a new date and fire the update function, only when I fire the function again does the updated data come through and display.

Comment: I've added my plant controller

Comment: It does return back my updated object

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your controller, you do not return the newly updated document after updating.

Try this

```
const plant = await Plant.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id },{...req.body},{new: true})
```

The new option must be set to true for Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate method to return a newly updated document, by default it's set to false hence always returning the original one.